# podSecurityContext not working as expected on init container

Tags: kubernetes, flyway, security-context

For the first time I am trying to set pod security context. I added the following to the pod spec:

```
securityContext:
  fsGroup: 2000
  runAsNonRoot: true
```

And when the pod is trying to come up, the init container is stuck in state `CreateContainerConfigError` with the following message:

```
Error: container has runAsNonRoot and image has non-numeric user (flyway), cannot verify user is non-root (pod: "mt-test-pod (c0cd-4c99-8501-1f592acae)", container: flyway-db-updater)
```

As I understand- there's a user named `flyway` but it is has no uid.

1. What should be done in order to make all containers in a pod **not** run as root?
2. Is there a specific way to define runAsNonRoot on init containers?

Answer (score 0):

Can you update the pod spec as given below

```
securityContext:
  fsGroup: 2000
  runAsUser: 1000
```

reference--> https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/#set-the-security-context-for-a-pod

Comment: `Error: failed to create containerd task: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec /flyway/flyway: permission denied: unknown`